# script to copy from source to target folder, how to exclude one folder from source folder

Tags: linux, bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source_folder=/samba

target_folder=~/.snapshot/$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

mkdir -p ~/.snapshot/$(date +"%d-%m-%Y") 

cd $source_folder

cp -r --preserve=ownership,mode  $source_folder/* $target_folder  

sudo find ~/.snapshot -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} +;
```

Comment: Please add more info on the folder or rules defining the folders to exclude, as well as some explanation on the lines of code you pasted. This is your first post, so the community will be more lenient, but you should really have a good read on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `odd_one` is the name of directory you want to exclude, you can do :

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r --preserve=ownership,mode  $source_folder/!(odd_one) $target_folder
```

As you use a normal use to write into ~/.snapshot, you should not use `sudo` to do `rm`.